# How to use a form on Redis and Ohm and without ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, redis, ohm

I am using redis as database and ohm as ActiveRecord replacement.

When I create a form for creating an object I may use the form_for viewhelper to easyly create forms to edit and create objects.

Is there something like that for ohm?

Best regards, hijolan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyShinyModel < Ohm::Model
  include ActiveModel::SomeModule

  # ...
end
```

And proceed like desribed here http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/ or here http://asciicasts.com/episodes/219-active-model.

Comment: thanx for the tip. sounds nice. I also found the ohm_contrib gem, that helps Ohm Models to act like other models.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no correlation between the ORM you are using and the ActionView form helpers.  As long as OHM is an implementation of the ActiveModel API, it should just work as expected.

Comment: that sounds good... but Ohm seems not to be derived from Active Model... :( Any other hints?